# Getting "The 'mongodb' provider is not supported with this command" Error when try to do mongoDB migrate with Prisma

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I'm developing some simple Todo App BE using NestJS with Prisma ORM and use MongoDB as the DB. I'm using a FREE and SHARED MongoDB cluster that is hosted in MongoDB Altas cloud. Also I added `0.0.0.0/0` to the network access tab so anyone can connect to the DB.

**schema.prisma** file

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Task {
  id      String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name    String?
  description String?
  status  TaskStatus @default(TODO)
}

enum TaskStatus {
  TODO
  INPROGRESS
  DONE
}
```

**.env** file

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@todoappdb.jfo3m2c.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

But when I try to run `npx prisma migrate dev --name init` command it gives following output

```
D:\todoapp-backend>npx prisma migrate dev --name init
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db"

Error: The "mongodb" provider is not supported with this command. For more info see https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb
   0: migration_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine\core\src\state.rs:250
```

Can someone point me what is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading some content, found that `prisma migrate` commands are for the SQL databases only since they have a rigid table structure. But MongoDB is a document database and those data are unstructured

So rather than running `prisma migrate` command we can use following command

```
npx prisma generate
```

This command creates the Prisma client that gives type-safe access to our database.

Reference - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4nxOv91vWI&ab_channel=Prisma

Answer (score 4):

According to the official documentation (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate):

**Prisma Migrate:**

> Does not apply for MongoDB
> Instead of migrate dev and related commands, use db push for MongoDB.

i.e

```bash
npx prisma db push
```

Answer (score 1):

In prisma docs: [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/mongodb/install-prisma-client-typescript-mongodb)

"Whenever you make changes to your Prisma schema in the future, you manually need to invoke prisma generate in order to accommodate the changes in your Prisma Client API."